# How do I check for VB-specific syntax and functions?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to be able to check VB code for VB-specific items (for example, vbCrLf instead of ControlChars.CrLF).  Is there anything (tool, VS setting or plug-in, etc.) that will check VB code for these?

Answer (score 2):

You might try fxCop, and investigate adding your own rules...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/03/11/549611.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Browse through the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.